# How do we get the answer for this bitwise operation?

Tags: python

I know how to get the answer but the last part after the "or" part `|` is confusing.

```
print((0b1101&~1)|(033>>0x2))
```

Comment: And what part of it is confusing you?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is unclear. Are you asking what `>>` does? Or what a `0x` prefix on a number means? Please be as clear as possible. We can't help you if we don't understand your question. See [ask].

Comment: I get a `SyntaxError` when I run this code.

Comment: @quamrana, it gives a syntax error with Python 3 but runs (and prints `14`) with Python 2.

Comment: @Chris: Does that mean that `033` in python 2 is considered octal?

Comment: @quamrana, [yes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-18), and [this changed in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers).

Answer (score 1):

> I know how to get the answer but the last part after the "or" part |
>   is confusing.

This statement: `(033>>0x2)`

Is taking an octal number `033`, which is 27 in decimal, and shifting it right by 2.

Comment: yes but final answer I'm getting in my calculator is 15 while it is being 14 in python 2, and I have worked for it on the paper I am still getting 15:(

Comment: `0b1101 & ~1 == 0b1101 & 0b1110 == 0b1100 == 0xC == 12`, and like I said in my answer `033 >> 0x2 == 27 >> 2 == 27/4 == 6` now we have `12 | 6 == 0b1100 | 0b0110 == 0b1110 == 0xE == 14`

Comment: Dear sir if its not bothering you , how come negation 1 has a binary value of 1110?

Comment: @LasanManujitha the bit length of `~1` matches the left hand operand, in this case the bit length is 4 so `~0b0001 == 0b1110`, but if the left hand operand had a bit length of 5 than it would be `~0b00001 == 0b11110` and so on